# How to draw a table layout with borders in Mono-android using C#?

Tags: xml, xamarin.android, tablelayout

How to draw a table layout with borders in Mono-android using C#?

Shape tag not working. I have written following code in a separate .xml file, but it shows " **Shape tag is not declared"**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#99FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="30px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you're missing the `/shape/android:shape` attribute Try using this as the contents of your .xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#99FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="30px"/>
    <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp" />    
</shape>
```

See also the Android [Shape Drawable documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).